# Abnormal return R

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics

I'm trying to compute the cumulative abnormal returns in R for multiples tickers on multiples stock exchanges for multiples years, with a windows of +1 day -1 day. Is there any R packages that I can use from there ?
I thought about abnormalReturn but would it mean I need to loop 3 times - 1 for the tickers, 1 for the market exchange, 1 for the year ?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyquant)
devtools::install_github("axelperschmann/AbnormalReturns")
library(AbnormalReturns)

date <- data$date
tickers <- data$tic
exchange <- data$exchange

price_data <- tq_get(tickers,
                     from = '1990-01-01',
                     to = '2021-03-01',
                     get = 'stock.prices')

ret_data <- price_data %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  tq_transmute(select = adjusted,
               mutate_fun = periodReturn,
               period = "daily",
               col_rename = "ret")

sapply(tickers, function(x){
tryCatch({
abnormalReturn(prices_stock = x, prices_market = y, from = z, to = z,
model = "marketmodel", estimationWindowLength = 10, c = 10)
}, error = function(u) NULL)
})
```

Thanks in advance